# How to sort/ascending in React using .map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of objects and I need to sort ascending based on the {i.u_dashboard} item. How would I go about sorting this?

```
const Results = () => {
    return (
      <>
        {
          results.map(i => (
              <ul>
                    <li
                      className={`colorDot && ${selectDashboard.name === i.u_dashboard && 'decreaseHeight'}`}
                      style={{ backgroundColor: determineDotColor(i.u_calls_in_queue) }}
                    ></li>
                    <li key={i.sys_id}><img src={logoMapper[i.u_dashboard]} alt="company logo"/><h1>{i.u_dashboard}</h1></li>
                    <li>Available Agents: <span className="callData">{i.u_agents_available}</span></li>
                    <li>Calls in Queue: <span className="callData">{i.u_calls_in_queue}</span></li>
                    <li>Longest Active Call: <span className="callData">{i.u_longest_active_call}</span></li>
                    <li>Longest Queued Call: <span className="callData">{i.u_longest_queued_call}</span></li>
                    <li>Queue Time Daily: <span className="callData">{i.u_queue_time_daily}</span></li>
                    <li>Queue Time MTD: <span className="callData">{i.u_queue_time_mtd}</span></li>
                    <li>Queue Time Last Month: <span className="callData">{i.u_queue_time_last_month}</span></li>
                    <li>Calls Taken MTD: <span className="callData">{i.u_calls_taken_mtd}</span></li>
                    <li>Calls Taken Last Month: <span className="callData">{i.u_calls_taken_last_month}</span></li>
                    {i.u_billable_tickets_closed_mtd && <li>BT Closed MTD: <span className="callData">{i.u_billable_tickets_closed_mtd}</span></li>}
                    {i.u_billable_tickets_closed_last_month && <li>BT Closed Last Month: <span className="callData">{i.u_billable_tickets_closed_last_month}</span></li>}
              </ul>
          ))
        }
      </>
    )
  }
```

Comment: What kind of value is i.u_dashboard? Is it a number or string?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, it is a string value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a sort function before the map, if they're compareable.

```
{
          results.sort((a,b) =>{ 
              if (a.u_dashboard < b.u_dashboard) {
                   return -1
              }
              if (a.u_dashboard > b.u_dashboard) {
                   return 1
              }
              return 0
              }).map(i => (
              <ul>
                    <li
                      className={`colorDot && ${selectDashboard.name === i.u_dashboard && 'decreaseHeight'}`}
                      style={{ backgroundColor: determineDotColor(i.u_calls_in_queue) }}
                    ></li>
                    <li key={i.sys_id}><img src={logoMapper[i.u_dashboard]} alt="company logo"/><h1>{i.u_dashboard}</h1></li>
                    <li>Available Agents: <span className="callData">{i.u_agents_available}</span></li>
                    <li>Calls in Queue: <span className="callData">{i.u_calls_in_queue}</span></li>
                    <li>Longest Active Call: <span className="callData">{i.u_longest_active_call}</span></li>
                    <li>Longest Queued Call: <span className="callData">{i.u_longest_queued_call}</span></li>
                    <li>Queue Time Daily: <span className="callData">{i.u_queue_time_daily}</span></li>
                    <li>Queue Time MTD: <span className="callData">{i.u_queue_time_mtd}</span></li>
                    <li>Queue Time Last Month: <span className="callData">{i.u_queue_time_last_month}</span></li>
                    <li>Calls Taken MTD: <span className="callData">{i.u_calls_taken_mtd}</span></li>
                    <li>Calls Taken Last Month: <span className="callData">{i.u_calls_taken_last_month}</span></li>
                    {i.u_billable_tickets_closed_mtd && <li>BT Closed MTD: <span className="callData">{i.u_billable_tickets_closed_mtd}</span></li>}
                    {i.u_billable_tickets_closed_last_month && <li>BT Closed Last Month: <span className="callData">{i.u_billable_tickets_closed_last_month}</span></li>}
              </ul>
          ))
        }
```

Not sure if it works as it should but this could be one solution.

Comment: Edited for strings, otherwise if not working try taking a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort